# Closed expression for $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{a^{2}-2ab\cos(x)+b^{2}}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

Suppose $a, b >0$. I'm looking for closed expressions for the following integral:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sqrt{a^{2}-2ab\cos(x)+b^{2}}dx $$
I tried to solve this by myself and got nowhere and even wolfram alpha couldn't get me an answer so maybe this is not easily solved, but might have some complicated closed expression. Any help is important. Thanks!

Comment: This is clearly an incomplete elliptic integral of the 2nd kind. Mathematica gives a closed form expression as a result, which may be obtained using some algebra and the definition from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind  I'm too lazy to write this up, so if anyone wants some quick and easy rep, please go on ahead :-)

Comment: What is the result given by Mathematica?

Comment: It gives 4 (a + b) EllipticE[(4 a b)/(a + b)^2], where EllipticE is the Elliptic integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not admit a closed form in terms of elementary functions for general $a,b>0$. However, using some elementary trigonometric identities and symmetry properties, one can get a solution in terms of elliptic integrals.

---

Firstly, by the substitution $u=x+\pi$ and the identity $\cos(u-\pi)=-\cos(u)$, one has
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(x)}~dx=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(u)}~du.$$
Using symmetry of $\cos(u)$ about $u=\pi$ and the identity $\cos(u)=1-2\sin^2(u/2)$, one has
$$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(u)}~du&=2\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(u)}~du\\&=2\int_0^{\pi} \sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab\sin^2(u/2)}~du\\&=4\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{(a+b)^2-4ab\sin^2(v)}~dv\\&=4(a+b)\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-\frac{4ab}{(a+b)^2}\sin^2(v)}~dv\\&=4(a+b)E\left(\frac{\sqrt{4ab}}{a+b}\right),\end{align}$$
where we have used the substitution $v=u/2$ and the definition of the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) according to Wikipedia
$$E(k):=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(\theta)}~d\theta.$$
Note that in some conventions the argument inside the elliptic integral is $k^2$ instead of $k$ (such as the one used by [Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html)).

---

**Sidenote:** Consider a circle of radius $a$ with center at a distance $b$ to the origin of $\mathbb{R}^2$. This integral comes up when computing the average distance from the origin to the points of this circle. Namely, one considers
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab\cos(x)}~dx.$$
Equivalently, it is distance travelled by a point at a distance of $b$ from the centre of a rolling disc with radius $a$ in one full rotation (forget the multiplicative factor outside the integral).

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica yields the result shown below when executig:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[a^2 - 2 ab*Cos[x] + b^2], {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

$$4 \sqrt{a^2+2 \text{ab}+b^2} E\left(\frac{4 \text{ab}}{a^2+b^2+2 \text{ab}}\right)$$

where $E(\ldots)$ denote the [complete Elliptic Integral](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EllipticE.html).

Comment: Comparing this answer with the others:  Mathematica uses the parameter $m=k^2$ and writes $E(m)$, while Wikipedia (and Maple, etc.) use the "elliptic modulus" $k=\sqrt{m}$ and write $E(k)$ .